# Can chrome packaged app downloaded from Play for Education use the Chrome Web Store Licensing API?

Tags: google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

Can a chrome packaged app installed from the Google Play for Education store still use the Chrome Web Store Licensing API to check when it was first installed? In the JSON response from the API that is the 'createdTime' value.

Although the app would be installed from the Play for Education store, it also would appear on the regular Chrome Web Store, so it seems possible that the Web Store Licensing API could still be accessible to it, and would still return the expected information, at least for 'createdTime'.

Comment: What do you call "Web Store API"?

Comment: @Xan I edited the question to clarify - the Chrome Web Store **Licensing** API. Here is the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments#verifying-payment).

Comment: Yes, saw it already. It's a valid question now, though I'd add a few tags..

Answer (score 0):

An answer from someone at Google in the Chrome and Education areas:

> "the web store API does not give back a createdTime for apps installed outside of the traditional individual install, so you should not count on this"